# low space on filesystem root ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and I am facing this type of error.what should i do.here is my gparted images.[image]

Comment: You didn't do a good job of planning for how much space would be needed in each partition.  There is plenty of space still available on the drive but to use it, you will need to redo partitions because the space isn't accessible.

Comment: so what can  I DO NOW,ANY TIPS  OR SUGGESTION,I CAN'T INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE BECAUSE OF LOW SYSTEM ON FILESYSTEM ROOT

Comment: The simplest solution might be to delete sda6 and extend sda3 to at least use the space.  Steal a chunk of space from sda5 (shrink that), and use the freed space to replace sda6. 30 or 40 GB ought to be plenty, and that loss from sda5 will hardly be noticeable.  You would need to reinstall Ubuntu.  Since Home is in a separate partition, you could reuse that without losing your files.

Comment: all of my installed software will be removed then? and will you please help me with step by step guide

Comment: You could back stuff up and restore it.  There is a utility available from Mint (MintBackup), that may work with Ubuntu.  It will make a list of everything you have added to the base distro, then reinstall those.  There would be a lot of manual work doing things like replacing GRUB, so it's often faster to just reinstall Ubuntu and reload the software.  But redoing partitions isn't a trivial task.

Comment: I can give you the gist, but for all the steps involved in the process, I've only had to do this a couple of times and it's been years.  So I'm probably not the best person to step you through the process, or to deal with issues if things go sideways.